# this title has been edited

Tags: bufferedreader

i edited this code because i cant delete it permanently . i edited this code because i cant delete it permanently . i edited this code because i cant delete it permanently . i edited this code because i cant delete it permanently 
.i edited this code because i cant delete it permanently

please do not re edit it

Comment: Clue: look what code the 2 methods have in common, extract that code to a new method and call it from both methods.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the loading of the file into the graph from the creation of the graph.

Something like this:

```
public interface GraphLoader {
    /**
     * Fill a graph with no property from a single file.
     *
     * @param graph the graph to fill
     * @param path path to graph file
     * @return a graph with no property
     */
    public static void loadSingleFile(Graph graph, Path path) {
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path.toFile()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] vertices = line.split(" ");
                if (vertices.length < 2) {
                    continue;
                }
                graph.addEdge(Integer.parseInt(vertices[0]), Integer.parseInt(vertices[1]));
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * load a graph with no property from a single file.
     *
     * @param path path to graph file
     * @return a graph with no property
     */
    public static Graph loadSingleFile(Path path) {
        Graph graph = new Graph();
        loadSingleFile(graph, path);
        return graph;
    }

    /**
     * load a graph with no property from multiple files in parallel.
     *
     * @param paths paths to graph files
     * @return a graph with no property
     */
    static Graph loadMultipleFiles(Path[] paths) {
        Graph graph = new Graph();
        for (Path path : paths) {
            loadSingleFile(graph, path);
        }
        return graph;
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer it was very helpful , i hope i can have your contact to ask you more question if that is not too much to ask

Comment: @benimane - Sorry - no personal contacts on SO - just post another question and someone will help.

Comment: i have posted another question and i appreciate if u can help me "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220825/similar-methods-with-a-slight-difference-can-i-merge-java#"

Comment: can you please delete your answer , i didnt know that code was confidentiel , please understand me

Answer (score 0):

1. Use "try with resources". 
   [Try with resources documentation by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)
2. Divide "catch" block in hierarchy order 
   [Advantages of exceptions by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/advantages.html)
3. Why do you use interface for this? Is it an architectural idea?